# No right click Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that should do one simple thing: When you right click, nothing happens. I've read Chrome's doc, many articles on this site, and many others, tried a lot of code, using background page or script, persistent or not, and various JavaScript code to neutralize right click.

Finally, I decided to ask here, because, it seems to me I'm missing one simple thing, but I can't find what.

I tried a lot of things, but let's start from the simplest one, in which I can't see what's wrong:

manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "norightclick",
  "description": "empecher le clic droit sur les pages",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["norightclick.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "contextMenus"
  ]
}
```

norightclick.js:

```
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false");
document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false");
```

I imported all this in Chrome, and nothing happens: no error message, but still the same context menus appearing when I right click on a page.

(It's just a "restart from the beginning", I've tried such a lot of things, it would be impossible to put them here).

Comment: There's quite a few questions about this on StackOverflow already, all of them with answers. I strongly suspect more than one of these already cover your question: [here](/questions/25815902), [here](/questions/15580330), and [here](/questions/13804213). Note that some don't literally cover your question, but *do* show you what you'd need to do, just for a different use case.

Comment: As Madhan pointed out, `new Function("return false");` is `eval` in disguise, which is evil.  The correct way would be `function() { return false; }`.  I would also recommend reading through Google's extension [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), since a confusion of a background script and a content script shows that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how extensions work.

Answer (score 3):

In my `manifest.json` file, I had to replace:

```
"background": { "persistent": false, "scripts": ["norightclick.js"] },
```

with :

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```

Then, rename `norightclick.js` to `content.js`

I found this on this page : 
[Developing google extensions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-google-chrome-extensions--net-33076)

Comment: glad you figured it out and reported back! this is how questions should be asked and answered! :)

Comment: Not exactly, no; you should mark this answer as accepted and not use "[Solved]" in the title. Please fix this

Comment: @Xan Wouldn't isolated worlds mean that a content script can't overwrite `onselectstart` and `oncontextmenu`?

Comment: You can leave your script named `norightclick.js`, you just have to reference it properly in your manifest.  That may be preferable, since a file named `content.js` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @Teepeemm Why are you asking me? Yes, it would not overwrite it if present, but it will execute this among others, denying the default handler.

Comment: @Xan : Solved has benn removed from title (a moderator, I suppose ?), but I can't mark my comment as accepted (4 hours max for that, apparently).

Comment: @zeltron80 There may be a timeout before you can accept your own answer; it probably means you will be able to do that 4 hours _later_. It wasn't a moderator - any user can edit (or suggest edits) to any posts. You can also always see the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your script. It should be

```
    document.oncontextmenu=function(){return false;};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Madhan, but I already tried lot of things like this, in my multiples attempts, and it didn't work. I didn't change my javascript at all, and made it work with the solution described just upon your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem, but you're correct that OP should be doing it this way instead.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yep after this op solved his problem by himself